# Calculate points of a tesseract (hypercube)

Tags: geometry, visualization

I would like to know how to calculate the points of a hypercube. I am trying to use the mac app Grapher to simulate what one would look like. Does anyone know the equation I could use to generate the shape?

Comment: Have you tried doing it for the square and cube? You might notice a pattern in the coordinates of the points.

Answer (score 0):

The coords of the hypercube of edge length 2, centered at the origin, and with facets being parallel to the coord planes, would be $(\pm1, \pm1, \pm1, ...)$. (Just continue up to the dimension you'd like.)
--- rk